# Convert graph of triangles into edges for the sake of coloring

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

I have graph made of triangles, and i need to color triangles. But i already have algorithm to color edges. Is there any known algorithm to convert graph in a way to correspond edge <-> triangle?

Two triangles must have different color if they share at least one vertex.

Comment: Here's something you can ponder on : let $G$ be your graph.  Create a triangle graph $T$ where you represent each triangle of $G$ as a vertex, and join two vertices if their corresponding triangles share a vertex.  Then the problem is to find a vertex coloring of $T$.  That would be an NP_Complete problem, unless you could characterize $T$ enough so that it'd be a polynomial-time colorable graph class.  Here I conjecture that $T$ is valid iff $T$ is $K_{1,4}$-free, which would make the problem NP-Complete (see http://www.graphclasses.org/classes/gc_388.html).